# How to visualize two kinds of search results

Tags: search, faceted-search

We are doing a system which is handling a large amount of data and it's using a search/filtering function similar to behance.net. This means that the filter area (criteria in the comboboxes) also act as a header for the search result!

[image]

In addition to this the user will also have to possibility to right click a cell in the table and choose "Filter by value" which will filter out all rows with that value (for instance xxx1 in the image). The question is how to let the user know that an additional filter has been added, since it is not a part of the criterias in the filter area?

Behance.net adds an additional row below the filter area, but it feels a bit confusing to have two different "headers" for what the table is showing. Does anyone has any experience of this kind?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would create a tag (badge) for each chosen filter. So you have a good overview of the current filter setup and are able to deselect/clear filter options with the "X". So you put the dropdown selection and text input value filter options on the same level of interaction.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA7E0a.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: @Sarah was this input helpful for you? Did you find a appropriate solution? We are curious about it :)